# GatsbyJS/GraphQL won't connect to Drupal

Tags: graphql, drupal-8, gatsby

I have tried following numerous tutorials on connecting Drupal, and GatsbyJS. For instance, in [this](https://medium.com/@OPTASY.com/how-to-get-gatsby-to-work-with-drupal-building-a-gatsby-site-with-a-decoupled-drupal-back-end-3e2bbda87155) article, I get to step 4.3b, "Pull Content from the Drupal 8 site using GraphQL" before everything fails.

I have followed every instruction, but GraphQL seems to be pulling from the temporary Gatsby page rather than the Drupal site I made. Queries such as "allNodeBlog" don't exist, and I'm not sure how to fix everything so I can get to pulling information from my Drupal JSON API page rather than the Gatsby site.

Any help/advice would be great. And/or articles that aren't simply the first Googled "Drupal and Gatsby" help sites (as I've looked at them all).

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Default Starter',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-drupal',
      options: {
        baseUrl: 'http://gatsbydrupal.dd:8083/',
        apiBase: 'api', // endpoint of Drupal server
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: 'gatsby-starter-default',
        short_name: 'starter',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/gatsby-icon.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you add your gatsby-config.js to the question?

Comment: Hi, I've attached my config file. I thought I had a different one, but maybe I've just messed with this one too many times. I'm sorry my response is so late! If you can still help, I would appreciate it. Right now I'm using Drupal to complete my task but my client would eventually like to find out if we can move it to Gatsby/React.

Comment: The tutorial says you have to use 'jsonapi' as the apiBase.. did you try that? And in general: do you get any error message?